# unmet dependencies when Installing GIMP

Tags: 11.10, software-installation, gimp

I can't install GIMP, it says something about unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gimp: Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.0-2 is to be installed
      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.24.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libgs9 (>= 8.61.dfsg.1) but 9.04~dfsg-0ubuntu11.5 is to be installed
      Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.6-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
      Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 147) but 1:173-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
      Depends: libjpeg62 (>= 6b1) but 6b1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.34.1-2 is to be installed
      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

Comment: In the future, consider downloading the DVD image of Ubuntu install disc and burn to a DVD or create a bootable pendrive with it. It's a bigger download, but saves you from downloading certain packages afterwards. It includes `GIMP` and `Inkscape`, so you have the most amazing graphics software installed off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

As `gimp` is a package that can be found in the Ubuntu repositories (i.e. you're not trying to install any non-supported application or beta version, etc), i suggest you try to solve the dependency issue instead of bypassing it.

Therefore, i would do the following:

- Look for and note all the `Depends: <package name>` statements in your error message (like **python-gtk2**, **libc6**, **libfontconfig1**, etc). These are the packages that have dependency issues.
- For each of these packages, do a `sudo apt-get remove <package name>` and then a `sudo apt-get install gimp`. Do this recursively. Each time you uninstall one package, then try to install `gimp`.

You should notice that the list of dependency issues should be smaller (that's not always the case, but let's keep it simple for now).
At some point - probably not all packages will have to be uninstalled - the installer should proceed with the installation of `gimp` as well as with all the necessary dependent packages at their 'correct' versions.

Give it a try and let us know how it went ;)

Comment: Ok so I tried it and got a bunch of pages of information, still not working though :/ should I just give it up? 
http://shortText.com/mvOkkD

Answer (score -1):

Open your terminal and use these commands please:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jmou/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

If that doesn't work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

may also help.

Comment: To the OP: Do read [this Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) question on adding PPAs before blindly typing these into the terminal.

Comment: I tried both that you listed for me and neither one of them worked for me. This is what it told me after trying to install the second one: http://shortText.com/MKQyHP

Comment: Can you please repair broken packages?